# trying to create a dictionary from a text file

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

fieldict(filename) reads a file in DOT format and 
 returns a dictionary with the DOT CMPLID, converted to an
 integer, as the key, and a tuple as the corresponding value
 for that key.  The format of the tuple is:
 (manufacturer, date, crash, city, state)

```
fieldict("DOT500.txt")[416]
  ('DAIMLERCHRYSLER  CORPORATION', datetime.date(1995, 1, 9), False, 'ARCADIA',
```

so far, I have tried

```
from collections import defaultdict
import datetime

def fieldict(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        x=[line.split('\t')[0].strip() for line in f] #list of complaint numbers
        y= line.split('\t') #list of full complaints
        d={}
        for j in x:
            Y= True
            N= False
            d[j] = tuple(y[2],datetime.date(y[7]), y[6], y[12], y[13])   #dict with number of complaint as key and tuple with index as values
        return d
```

No luck... I think I am close..any help is greatly appreciated

EDIT: each complaint is formatted like this

```
'11\t958128\tDAIMLERCHRYSLER CORPORATION\tDODGE\tSHADOW\t1990\tY\t19941117\tN\t0\t0\tENGINE AND ENGINE COOLING:ENGINE\tWILMINGTON  \tDE\t1B3XT44KXLN\t19950103\t19950103\t\t1\tENGINE MOTOR MOUNTS FAILED, RESULTING IN ENGINE NOISE. *AK\tEVOQ\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tV\t\r\n'
```

Entry without character marks showing :

```
11  958128  DAIMLERCHRYSLER CORPORATION DODGE   SHADOW  1990    Y   19941117    N   0   0   ENGINE AND ENGINE COOLING:ENGINE    WILMINGTON      DE  1B3XT44KXLN 19950103    19950103        1   ENGINE MOTOR MOUNTS FAILED, RESULTING IN ENGINE NOISE.  *AK EVOQ
```

Comment: Could you give an example of the content of the file?

Comment: there are 500 complaints in the file from the department of Transportation... Each is formatted like this:

Comment: Why not just show two lines? (You can edit them into the question)

Comment: the above is the 11th entry in the file

Comment: Someone else was also working on this question the other day and received some help which might be useful to you too -- see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13111784/python-read-file-in-dot-format-and-return-city-name-list) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13128440/dictionary-comprehension-how-do-we-build-a-dictionary-with-integers-as-keys-and).

Comment: thanks, DSM, I think this will help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want to make friends with the [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module, as this looks like tab formatted csv text.  The `csv.reader()` has a `.next()` method which is called when you throw it in a for loop, so you can go line by line through the file.

As a general tip, read PEP8, and use understandable variable names.
With python, if it starts to feel hard that's a good sign that there usually is a better way.

```
import csv
import datetime

def _build_datetime(line)
    year_idx = x
    month_idx = y
    day_idx = z
    indexes = (year_idx, month_idx, day_idx)

    result_datetime = None
    if all(line[idx] for idx in indexes): # check that expected values are populated
        int_values = [int(line[idx]) for idx in indexes]
        result_datetime = datetime.date(*int_values)
    return result_datetime

def format2dict(filename):
    complaints = {}
    with open(filename, "rb") as in_f:
        reader = csv.reader(in_f, delimiter='\t')
        complaint_id_idx = 0
        manufacturer_idx = 2
        crash_idx = x
        city_idx = 12
        state_idx = 13

        for line in reader:
            complaint_id = int(line[complaint_id_idx])
            data= (
                         line[manufacturer_idx], 
                         _build_datetime(line),
                         line[crash_idx],
                         line[city_idx],
                         line[state_idx],
                        )

            complaints[complaint_id] = data
    return complaints


if __name__ == "__main__":
    formatted_data = format2dict("DOT500.txt")
```

Answer (score 2):

Note: Trimming the newline is left up to the reader.

A clean way of accomplishing this is to use `dict(zip(headers,data_list))`

Presuming your sample data looks like

```
joe\tSan Francisco\tapple
frank\tNew York City\torange
tim\tHawaii\tpineapple
```

You could do something like:

```
results = []
headers = ['person','place','fruit']

for line in open('datafile.txt').readlines():
    record = line.split('\t')
    results.append(dict(zip(headers,record)))
```

Which will make a dict for each line and append it to the end of 'results'.

Looking like:

```
[{'fruit': 'apple\n', 'person': 'joe', 'place': 'San Francisco'},
 {'fruit': 'orange\n', 'person': 'frank', 'place': 'New York City'},
 {'fruit': 'pineapple\n', 'person': 'tim', 'place': 'Hawaii'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track with line.split('\t') to break up text into pieces. Try something like this to build up the tuple from the split pieces.

```
import datetime

a = '11\t958128\tDAIMLERCHRYSLER CORPORATION\tDODGE\tSHADOW\t1990\tY\t19941117\tN\t0\t0\tENGINE AND ENGINE COOLING:ENGINE\tWILMINGTON  \tDE\t1B3XT44KXLN\t19950103\t19950103\t\t1\tENGINE MOTOR MOUNTS FAILED, RESULTING IN ENGINE NOISE. *AK\tEVOQ\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tV\t'

fields = a.split('\t')
recordNum = fields[0]
mfr = fields[2]
recDate = datetime.date(int(fields[5]),1,2)
make = fields[4]
DOTrecord = recordNum,mfr, recDate,make
print DOTrecord
```